# Wamp server can't bind to port 80 error

Tags: wamp

I'm having a very similar error to [Getting an error when starting WAMP - "VirtualHost *:80 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006/getting-an-error-when-starting-wamp-virtualhost-80-mixing-ports-and-no/39321#39321)

I'm getting the same

```
Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. : make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80"
```

error message in the event logs viewer. I tried the fix of disabling skype from using port 80 however when I do that nothing comes up in the console. I am using 64 bit wamp, im in a 64 bit windows 8.1 laptop.

Edit: Problem resolved, changed Listening on 80 to 8080 in httpd.cfg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a menu item on the WAMPManager icon ( the one in the system tray ) called `Test Port 80`

You get to it by

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Test Port 80
```

This will load a command window and show you the name of the other application that has captured port 80.

Then you have to work out what to do about it of course.

Also as far as I am aware the Windows 8 tiled version of SKYPE does not have any way of being configured to stop using port 80. But if you uninstall the Tile version of SKYPE and install the normal Windows version, that allows you to configure it so it will not attempt to use port 80 or 443.

**If you really cannot find  the wampmanager icon** try this instead

Try this

```
netstat -anop TCP | find ":80"
tasklist /FI "PID eq 999" /FO TABLE /NH

replacing 999 with the PID number from the previous command that is using port 80.
```

Comment: Didn't have a desktop icon however looked up the command line to do and and that didn't work however on that that same page it suggested changing to a different port like 8080 and that worked.

Comment: Its not a desktop icon, its and icon in the **system tray** > bottom right of the screen unless you have changed the default desktop.

Comment: See alternate methind of finding what is using port 80. I amended my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Other programs can mess with this.

Are you using Skype by chance or any other program.

If you are just turn it off and then launch wamp and then launch your program.

Comment: Skype is a common source of problem for Wamp

Comment: "I tried the fix of disabling skype from using port 80" but when i try to run wamp then nothign at all comes up in the console

Answer (score 0):

Open Command Prompt and run `netstat -ano | findstr :80`

That will list all connections and their process ID (on the right) that are using port 80. Match them with process IDs in your task manager and close them.